# VUE scroll-to from subpage to index page anchor

Tags: vue.js, scrollto

I am trying to scroll via v-scroll-to to an anchor in frontpage it works fine but if i navigate from subpage to indexpage anchor doesnt work because the anchor not in the DOM. How can is solve this problem?

`<a v-for="menuItem in menuItems" :key="menuItem.id" :class="{'is-active': activeMenuItem === menuItem}" :href="menuItem.url" v-scroll-to="menuItem.url">{{ menuItem.text !== '' ? $t(menuItem.text) : '' }}</a>`

The menuItem.url included the anchor.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with a simplified example of what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this issue because might be useful for you.
https://github.com/rigor789/vue-scrollto/issues/100

I haven't used vue-scrollto, but according to this issue, it probably works by the following code.

```
<a v-for="menuItem in menuItems" :key="menuItem.id" :class="{'is-active': 
activeMenuItem === menuItem}" :href="menuItem.url" @click="$scrollTo('#element')">{{ 
menuItem.text !== '' ? $t(menuItem.text) : '' }}</a>
```